# random forest predictor in new data does not match training data r

Tags: r, random-forest

I have a RF model in R, which was able to correctly predict results from the testing set. I am measured the variable pf correctly

```
> str(testing)
'data.frame':   4489 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ pf               : Factor w/ 1755 levels 
 $ p.E              : Factor w/ 24 levels
 $ p.EF             : Factor w/ 30 levels
 $ p.B              : Factor w/ 9 levels 
 $ p.BC             : Factor w/ 26 levels
 $ p.L              : num  110 122 201 60 9 ...
 $ p.N              : Factor w/ 9 levels 
 $ p                : num  580 
 $ pt               : Factor w/ 30 levels
```

I wanted to generate some new data to try and use in the model, so I made some new data, which was identical to the first line of the testing set, to try and predict pf:

```
> df=testing[1,]
> df=droplevels(df)
> str(df)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ pf               : Factor w/ 1 level
 $ p.E              : Factor w/ 1 level
 $ p.EF             : Factor w/ 1 level
 $ p.B              : Factor w/ 1 level
 $ p.BC             : Factor w/ 1 level
 $ p.L              : num 110
 $ p.N              : Factor w/ 1 level
 $ p                : num 580
 $ pt               : Factor w/ 1 level
```

and received the following error:

```
> predict(model,df,type='class')
Error in predict.randomForest(model, df, type = "class") : 
  Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data.
```

Could someone explain why this occurred or suggest how I could fix this?

Should I not have dropped the levels in my new df, which defeats the purpose of making a model to try and predict results based on new data? Or am I mising something blindingly obvious?

Comment: If you included your complete code with data examples that are able to be recreated it can be easier for people to help.

Comment: You should not drop levels. This does not 'defeat the purpose'.  The new data must express each factor in terms of the same levels as the training set.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know why, but the suggestions above did not work.

To fix it, I made a new row of values, altered a value, entered it as the last row of my test set, then ran the prediction on that last row.

```
df=testing[1,]
df[9]=as.factor(4)
testing=rbind(testing,df)
predict(model, testing[4490,],type='class')
```

This worked

Comment: In what sense are you saying this "worked". It's possible that it ran without error and gave you a prediction, but it seems much less clear that the prediction had any sensible relation to the train set.